# WIX install windows service

Tags: installation, wix, windows-services, wix3.6

I want to install a Windows Service. With installutil.exe it is running fine but
with WIX it stands still at "starting service"

```
<Component Id="CMP_Service" Feature="Core">
        <File Source="$(var.Service.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <ServiceInstall Id="Service"
                        Name="Service"
                        Description="..."
                        Start="auto"
          Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" 
          Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]"
                        ErrorControl="normal"
                        Type="ownProcess"/>
        <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControllELS"
                        Name="Service"
                        Start="install"
                        Stop="both"
                        Remove="uninstall"
                        Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
```

I think it is installing the wrong service but don´t know.
May someone help me?

Comment: also the installed service is not startable

Comment: Most likely it is a password that is incorrect. Please [skim this answer from "Quick Checks" onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55087943/129130). Follow the links to debugging check lists of various sorts.

Comment: The problem was some old dll´s which were included

Comment: OK, great. Fixed. Were the check lists helpful? Or maybe just the event log helped?

Comment: I have overwritten every dll with dll´s from the running version and found the old dlls

Comment: I use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=gallery) to diff folders and files. Commercial, no affiliations (just good software).